# Can not connect to a specific ftp address from a specific location

Tags: ftp, router

For some reason, from my office I can't connect to specific ftp address.  I can connect to it, from elsewhere, like my home.  I can connect to it via http and ping.  I access dozens of sites via ftp on a daily basis, so it's something about this site from my location.  How do I go about determining what the problem is?

It may be my ISP or ever my local router, or what else?

Comment: Does your company run an ftp proxy?

Comment: Try `traceroute <ip>` to discover where along the path to the ftp server your connection is blocked. If the `traceroute` makes it all the way, use a tool such as `lft` or `tcptraceroute` to try tracing the route using TCP instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something in your office is filtering the connection.

If I had to guess, they are preventing outbound FTP connections out of misguided security concerns.

Comment: I should clarify, this is a small company, so we don't have a big IT department (just me), actively maintaining the firewall and access policies.

Comment: Never figured out the specifics of this, but it was, indeed, something at our local router and / or isp setup, as we could access this otherwise.  We changed domains and didn't have the problem again.